# npm warning for not installed/outdated package, when installing iohook

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

When i ran `npm install iohook --save` i get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\italo\Documents\binder> npm install iohook --save
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\italo\Documents\binder\node_modules\iohook
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! Downloading prebuild for platform: iohook-v0.9.3-node-v115-win32-x64
Downloading prebuild.tar.gz                                                                                                                                                              
npm ERR! Error: GET https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook/releases/download/v0.9.3/iohook-v0.9.3-node-v115-win32-x64.tar.gz returned 404                                                  
npm ERR! Prebuild for current platform (iohook-v0.9.3-node-v115-win32-x64) not found!
npm ERR! Try to build for your platform manually:
npm ERR! # cd node_modules/iohook;
npm ERR! # npm run build
npm ERR!
npm ERR! C:\Users\italo\Documents\binder\node_modules\iohook\install.js:16
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\italo\AppData\Local\Temp\prebuild.tar.gz'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4058,
npm ERR!   code: 'ENOENT',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\italo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\prebuild.tar.gz'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v20.10.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\italo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-10T22_54_41_368Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\italo\Documents\binder>
```

Why do i get this error, and how to fix?:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@electron-toolkit/preload": "^2.0.0",
    "@electron-toolkit/utils": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "electron-updater": "^6.1.1",
    "har-validator": "^5.1.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-toolkit/eslint-config-prettier": "^1.0.1",
    "@electron-toolkit/eslint-config-ts": "^1.0.0",
    "@electron-toolkit/tsconfig": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.17.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.4",
    "electron": "^25.6.0",
    "electron-builder": "^24.6.3",
    "electron-vite": "^1.0.27",
    "eslint": "^8.47.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "prettier": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "^4.4.9"
  }
```

Comment: https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook/issues/438 - you probably need to look for a dependency that's getting maintained.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).